# How to avoid hard-coding of vendor id in device_filter.xml?

Tags: android, usb

I added the device_filter.xml to detect an attachment of a usb device. In order to avoid hard-coding of the vendor id and product id, I added integer resources into the values folder and named them 'vendor_id' and 'product_id', respectively. And then I wrote code in device_filter.xml as follows:

```
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="@integer/vendor_id" product-id="@integer/product_id" />
</resources>
```

But this doesn't work for me. If I change the values to digits (e.g. vendor-id="1234"), then it works.

Is there any way to avoid the hard-coding of the values? Or did I miss something?

Thank you so much!